# JAVA - How to make a purchases.products.acknowledge request

Tags: java, request, http-post, rest, acknowledgepurchase

I have to make a request with the POST method as described in the guide: https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.products/acknowledge

My Java code currently looks like this:

```
        httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        post = new HttpPost("https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications");
        ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("packageName", "com.my.app"));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("productId", productID));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("token", token));
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        response = httpClient.execute(post);
```

I receive a 404 web page, page not found, what am I wrong with my request?

Thanks to everyone who will try to help me. I love you <3

Answer (score 0):

Without having knowledge about your HTTPClient...
I think you are using the wrong URL.

That is from the docs:
`https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/{packageName}/purchases/products/{productId}/tokens/{token}:acknowledge`

and your URL simply is:
`https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications`

Besides that, i think you are posting the params for the URL as an entity in the payload. Instead you have to fill the variables in the url with it.

The only allowed entity in the payload is in the form of:

```
{
  "developerPayload": string
}
```